# Why does the first character in my String incorrect whereas the rest is correct?

Tags: assembly, arm

I have a string,"Kwjlmfhrdsb%atm%azi3\n", that must be read and altered if the ascii value in decimal is odd or even. My string is changed at every position. The expected output is: "Froqhkmwing \yh \d." However, I am getting the output: ".roqhkmwing \yh \d." I tried checking with gdb step by step but it seems that 'F' ('K' changed to 'F') is stored correctly into r1. I don't understand why that it is just the first index of the string that has the incorrect character. If someone could shed some light on what is occurring here, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
    .global _start

 _start:
    mov r7, #4
    mov r0, #1
    ldr r1, =string @ get addresss of string
    mov r5, #0  @ index

loop:
    ldrb r3, [r1, r5]   @getting value at string[i]
    @ add r6, r1, r5
    cmp r3,#10      @checking for new line at end of string
    beq print

    and r4, r3, #1  @if odd, r4 = 1
    cmp r4, #1  @checking if odd
    beq odd     @branch if odd

    @ else add 5 if even
    add r3, #5
    b temp
mid_loop:
    add r5, #1  @incrementing index

    bal loop    @go back to loop

temp:
    strb r3, [r1]   @storing new character back into the same index
    @ strb r3, [r6]
    bal mid_loop
odd:
    sub r3, #5
    bal temp
print:
    mov r7, #4
    mov r0, #1
    mov r2, #21
    ldr r1, =string
    swi 0
    b _exit
_exit:
    mov r7, #1
    swi 0

    .data

string:   @ 12345678901234567890
    .asciz "Kwjlmfhrdsb%atm%azi3\n"
```

Comment: IMO the code you posted would not modify anything else than first char of string, due to `strb r3, [r1]` where `r1` is never updated. Are you sure the code you posted is the code you did debug? (I didn't actually try to assemble + run, so I may be wrong).

Comment: Yes, it's the same.

Comment: Can you then check in `gdb`, why the other memory is modified, when you write to the constant `r1` address every char? :-o (or where is the `r1` increment I'm missing, and why the code doesn't read then every other character, as the index `r5` is incremented)

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure you let your brain fool you. The last character is `'3'`, and that is odd value `51`, after -5 you will get value `46`, which is ASCII encoding for `'.'` character. So your output is `.wjlmfhrdsb%atm%azi3`, only first char is modified. When reading output and code in debugger, make sure you read the actual screen, the brain will try hard to shortcut by "reading" code you did want to write originally, instead of reading the actual thing in source, which makes finding typos after yourself so difficult. Keep training your focus and skill to read your own source.

Comment: I got it. I changed the line, `strb r3, [r1]` to `strb r3, [r1, r5]`. Thanks for your help @Ped7g